# Error:(32, 27) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to long

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to Java.

> Error:(40, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   Error:(32, 27) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to long

at

```
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return hashMap.get(item);
    }
```

Full code is given below

```
package com.javapapers.android.listview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    int textViewResourceId;
    private static final String TAG = "SimpleArrayAdapter" ;
    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();

    public SimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                              List objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            hashMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return hashMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(String object){
        hashMap.put(object,hashMap.size());
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem you are having stems from the fact that `hashMap.get(item)` returns an `Object`, but your method signature specifies that you need to return a `long`.

```
public long getItemId(int position) {   // you say you will return a long
    String item = getItem(position);
    return hashMap.get(item);           // but try to return an Object
}
```

There is no way in Java for the JVM to *automatically* convert any random `Object` into a `long`, so the compiler is giving you that error.

There are a couple ways to fix this.

### The Wrong Way

The first (bad) way is *cast* the variable you are getting from the map to `long` like so:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {   // you say you will return a long
    String item = getItem(position);
    return (long)hashMap.get(item);     // and you return a long
}
```

This will make your code compile, but effectively what you are doing here is promising the compiler that you are really, *really* sure that what you put in the `Map` is a `Long`.  At this point the compiler will attempt to unbox the `Long` into a `long` and return it.  If it really was a `Long` this will work, and if not you will get a `ClassCastException` thrown.

### The Right Way

In newer versions of Java, there is something called [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).  Using Generics you can specify the allowed type of object which can be added to a container when you define it, like so:

```
// create a HashMap where all keys are Objects and all values are Longs
Map<Object, Long> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

public long getItemId(int position) {   // you say you will return a long
    String item = getItem(position);
    return hashMap.get(item);           // no cast is required
}
```

Now, the compiler will only allow values of type `Long` to be stored in your map, and anything you `get()` from it will automatically be a `Long`, removing the need (and danger) of casting the return type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should declare type params in your hashmap like so:

```
HashMap<String, Long> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

Then you should be able to cast the hash map value to long implicitly without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is telling you that the function "getItemId(int position)" does not exist anywhere else in your inheritance tree (namely above your current file).  Therefore, you don't want the "@override" before the function name.

Also, your hashmap does not declare the type of data it holds.  When you call hashmap.getItem(position) it is returning an object of some type and your function definition says it returns a long, therefore you need to be sure your hashmap contains either longs or something that can be converted to a long, and that is what is returned from getItem.